# What happens if i have the same function prototype in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a very simple code that is using inheritance, and I have the same function prototype in my base and derived classes. I don't understand the last result (`pB->bar()`), because I thought that since `pB` points to a derived type object (after `delete`) it should invoke `D::bar()`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class B {
    public:
        virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B:foo" << std::endl; }
        void bar() { std::cout << "B:bar" << std::endl; }
};

class D : public B {
    public:
        virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "D:foo" << std::endl; }
        void bar(){ std::cout << "D:bar" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    B* pB = new B;
    pB->foo();
    pB->bar();
    delete pB;
    pB = new D;
    pB->foo();
    pB->bar();
    delete pB;
}
```

the results of this are:

```
B:foo
B:bar
D:foo
B:bar
```

Comment: What exactly do you think the `virtual` keyword is for?

Comment: An interesting topic you should explore is vtable lookups if you want to learn more about why this behaves the way it does and how the `virtual` keyword affects the generated assembly for method dispatching.

Answer (score 3):

You have used `virtual` for `foo` but not `bar`. This program demonstrates the effect of that keyword: it signals to consider the dynamic or runtime type of the object. Without it, the compiler generates a direct function call using only the static or compile-time type information.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `virtual` creates a virtual table for the class function, then when you use a pointer to a class the program check the type of the class and try to find the function foo in the virtual table.

when you call bar the program check the class pointer for the implementation of bar and because the pointer is of type B the function bar of B is called.

you can wright

```
D* pD = new D;
pD->bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

`bar()` is not `virtual`, so calls to it are resolved statically at compile-time using the type it is called on.  It is not resolved dynamically at runtime, like you are expecting, similar to `foo()`, which is `virtual`.

Calling `bar()` via a `B*` pointer will call `B::bar()`, and calling it via a `D*` pointer will call `D::bar()` instead.  `pB` is a `B*`, so that is why `pB->bar()` calls `B::bar()` regardless of whether `pB` points at a `B` or `D` object. It is a static call.